# How to save the result of scraping in a CSV?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I'm scraping the website [www.kayak.it](http://www.kayak.it) from different links for an academic project.
I need to save the result of web-scraping in a CSV. Following my code.
I need to have all the scraping of the different links in a single csv, but I am not able to do that with the code that I have. Thank you for helping!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

list_link = ['https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-PAL/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0', 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-ROM/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0']

for link in list_link:
  #driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path")
  driver.maximize_window()
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  driver.get(link)
  time.sleep(5)
  flights = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("resultInner")
  flights_dict = dict() # To add the dictionaries within a dictionary
  #flight_dict = [] # To add the dictionaries in a list.
  i = 1
  print(len(flights))
  for flight in flights:
      driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", flight)
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,-300)")
      flightdetails = {}
      frowdet = []
      details = flight.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='mainInfo']//li")
      for d in details:
          fd = ""
          sd = ""
          first = d.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='top']")
          for f in first:
              fd += f.get_attribute("innerText") + ' '
          second = d.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='bottom']//span")
          for s in second:
              sd += s.get_attribute("innerText")
          detstr = sd + ' - ' + fd
          frowdet.append(detstr)

      fprice = flight.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='price-text']").get_attribute("innerText")[:2]
      flightdetails["Flights"] = frowdet
      flightdetails["Price"] = fprice
      #print(flightdetails)
      flights_dict[i] = flightdetails
      i+=1
      #flight_dict.append(flightdetails) # Append dictionaries to a list.

  print(flights_dict)
  driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I would suggest looking in to the Pandas library.

If you just need it directly in to a csv, use the `csv` library.
https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-csv-file/

I prefer to use pandas, which allows you to write the scraped data in to a dataframe, which you can then export to either a CSV or excel with ease. Here's an example:

```
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'Stock Name' : names,
    'Dimensions' : dimensions,
    'Area (m2)' : areas,
    'Length (m)' : lengths,
    })

dataframe.to_excel("output.xlsx")
dataframe.to_csv("output.csv")
```

In the above code, i state the column names, and then the list names i want in that column. So, the column named `Stock Name` will contain every index of my list in python called `names`. Then i output it to both xlsx and csv.

Using a dataframe will format it nicely for you to use. Pandas has tons of functionality that allows you to join workbooks, join sheets and so on for Excel, but it's probably easier for you to scrape it all in to one list within python then write it to a CSV directly.

See here for Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Python has built-in module for such tasks named `csv`, as you have list of `dict`s you might use [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), consider following simple example:

```
import csv
squares = [{'x':1,'square':1},{'x':2,'square':4},{'x':3,'square':9}]
with open('squares.csv','w',newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['x', 'square']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(squares)
```

create file `squares.csv` with following content

```
x,square
1,1
2,4
3,9
```

Note that by default `csv.DictWriter` use dialect `excel`, so you should be then be able to easily import it into Excel if you wish

Answer (score 0):

you can write your final results in csv in this way:

```
import io

with io.open('output.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for item in flights_dict:
        #print(item)
        #print(flights_dict[item])
        file.write('%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n'%(item,list(flights_dict[item].keys())[0],list(flights_dict[item].values())[0][0],list(flights_dict[item].values())[0][1],list(flights_dict[item].keys())[1],list(flights_dict[item].values())[1]))
    file.close()
```

[here is results in csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjVfH.png)